# yii onclick update a renderPartial

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I am working on a project using Yii framework.  Currently the page loads correctly and passes the variables : picks : an array of 16 picks, ticket_ID : just a normal ID.

What I am trying to do is when the reset button is pushed, call the js function that sets an array of 16, refresh the my_picks div and passes the new array to the renderPartial.  Currently I am having issues in passing the variables to the container and not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any hint would help.  Thank you for your time.
code below:

```
<div class="regional_div regional_div_my_picks" id="my_picks" >
    <?php echo $this->renderPartial('container/my_picks_div', array('picks' => $my_picks,'ticket_ID' => $ticket_ID));?>
    <div class="picks">
        <!--save-->
        <a style="width:100%;" href="#">Save</a>
        <!--radom select all seeds-->
        <a style="width:100%;" href="#">Random</a>
        <!--reset all seeds-->
        <a style="width:100%;" onclick="my_picks_reset()" id="my_picks_reset">Reset</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    /*set var picks = array of 16 to TBA and reset th my_picks div*/
    $("#my_picks_reset").click(function() {
        var picks =     array('TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA') 
        $("#my_picks").load('container/my_picks_div', array('picks' => picks,'ticket_ID' => $ticket_ID))
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: do you have actionMy_picks_div in your ContainerController?

Comment: because that is what your .load() is requesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make an action in the controller, that'll render the my_picks_div to the ajax request. Such as `actionGetPicksDiv()`.

Just make a regular action, perhaps set a ajaxOnly access rule for it, and use `renderPartial()` in it (no `render`, you dont want a layout).

Answer (score 0):

It took some time to understand but it works now.

```
 function save_picks(){
    var data = {};
    var url = 'some/url'
    $('input:checked').each(function(){
        var team_ID = $(this).val();
        var seed = $(this).attr('seed');
        data[seed] = team_ID;
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { team_IDs : data , ticket_ID : <?php echo $ticket_ID; ?>},
        success: function(){
            window.location.href();
        }
    });

}


 public function actionSavepicks(){
     /*somecodehere*/
 }
```